# How do I tell R to always use Cairo for plotting?

Tags: r, cairo

I have been using Cairo when I generate plots in R, but I always use `CairoWin()` before each plot.  Is there a way I can tell R to use Cairo for the whole session as soon as I start working?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Haven't tested, but probably as easy as:

```
options(device="CairoWin")
```

And if you put that in your .Rprofile, it  will be the default in all your R sessions.

Comment: Everything runs in the console, but no graphics device comes up.

Comment: You need to supply a function to this option, try `options(device=CairoWin)`

Comment: @James, I still don't get any graphics popping up.

Comment: @Nazer: run `dev.off()` until you get `null device` as the output.

Comment: Got it, I just needed to turn the first device off.  Thanks!

Comment: Run `dev.list` to find which graphics devices are active then enter the index numers of the devices you want to turn off e.g. `dev.off(1, 2)`

Comment: How to supply arguments to `CairoWin`?